# How to Rename Files with Subdirectories?

Tags: powershell

Good Morning,

I have hundreds of files in subfolders with a root directory of - "C:\Layout\PDF"
The files are 7 digits with "_Email". (ie 9991234_Email.pdf)
How can I get a PowerShell Script to change the file names within all of the subdirectories to be 7 digits with "_Proof" Instead? (ie 9991234_Proof.pdf)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

```
$inPath = 'C:\Layout\PDF\'
$outPathRoot = 'C:\Layout\PDF\'
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -LiteralPath $inPath -Filter *_Email.pdf | ForEach-Object {


$targetDir = New-Item -Type Directory -Force ($outPathRoot)

$EmailFiles =  Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "_Email*"}
ForEach($File in $EmailFiles) 
{
    $newname = ([String]$File).Replace("_Email","_Proof")
    Rename-item -Path $File $newname
}
```

Comment: You would need `Get-ChildItem` and `Rename-Item`.

Comment: It would help if you would explain how the script you have is failing to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Rename-Item`'s parameter `-NewName` accepts a *scriptblock* (`{..}`) that allows for robust renaming. So, by referencing the current objects' in the pipeline name property (`$_.Name`), you can call on `.Replace()` to replace `Email`, with `Proof`.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Layout\PDF\' -Filter '*_Email.pdf' -Recurse | 
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('Email','Proof') } -WhatIf
```

---

*Remove the `-WhatIf` common/safety parameter when you've dictated those are the results you're after*.

Comment: Abraham,  
Thank you for your response, however, it did not seem to work.
I have a test file "9991234_Email.pdf in a subfolder
C:\Layout\PDF\9900000-9999999\9990000-9999999\
and the file has remained 9991234_Email.pdf

Also, I am running the script from the Root Directory

Comment: @BryanBishopPagenkopf, did you remove the `-WhatIf`?

Comment: Ha!  I had not.  Sorry!   did it now and it worked perfectly!